# LoadXMLByUrl: Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode

```
@synthesize xmlcont;
```

**And**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
/* Line 35 */ xmlcont =[[pxmlC alloc]loadXMLByUrl:@"http://openmenu.com/api/v1/restaurant?key=57d3661c-0fa1-11e1-80ac-00163eeae34c&name=rusc"];
for (pxml *t in [xmlcont xmlArray]) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ %d",[t rname],[[xmlcont xmlArray] indexOfObject:t] );
}
NSLog(@"abc");
[super viewDidLoad];}
```

**And**

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [xmlcont release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**But Build ans Analyze said**:

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line 35

**When I click ">", it said:**

> Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning
>   reference)
>
> Object allocated on line 35 is no longer referenced after this point
>   and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

Like this:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/af6b3.png

I can't understand...
***Please help me fix it.
Thank you so much ^^***

Answer (score 0):

If your property is declared as retain you should set it via the accessor and autorelease

```
self.xmlcont = [[[pxmlC alloc] loadXMLByUrl:@"http://openmenu.com/api/v1/restaurant?key=57d3661c-0fa1-11e1-80ac-00163eeae34c&name=rusc"] autorelease];
```

also you should follow naming conventions and have an `init` or `init...` initializer. If there is one you should call `init` bebore calling `loadXMLByUrl`.

Comment: Thank for your answer...
I just started learning so do not know how to name.//.

In my app,
I tried as you said. but not effective
@_@

Comment: Please post you pxml header, and name your classes with an upper case first letter...

Comment: Before: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/af6b3.png
and After: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/9aafb.png ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the analyzer is confused by the ill-named initializer. Initializer names have to start with `init…`, so that the analyzer knows the method will return the receiver. Rename your `loadXMLByUrl` initializer to `initWithContentsOfURL` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.
But I have defined -(id)loadXMLByUrl:(NSString *)urlString in .h and .m files

Comment: You have to *rename* the method from `loadXMLByUrl` to `initWithContentsOfURL`, that should help.

Comment: this is my (id)loadXML... [http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/c2fa2.png ] I have used `initWithContentOfURL`

Comment: We don’t understand each other. Your class has an initializer called `loadXML`. That’s a bad name, because it confuses the code analyzer. You have to *rename the method* to `initWithContentsOfURL` or anything else that starts with “init”.

Comment: Look. If you want to get rid of the analyzer warning, try to rename the method. It’s all I can say.

Comment: Thank you... i'll try like you said. I'm learning Parsing XML... it's so difficult.